# Named views alongside child routes

Tags: vue-router

This will go haywire on me with none of the routes registering as error logs claim.

```
{
    path: '/auction',
    name: 'auction',
    // component: '/imports/ui/auctionPage.vue',
    components: {
        default: auctionPage,
        sidebar: filters,
    },
    children: {
        path: 'item/:id',
        component: "modalComponent"
    }
},
```

Perhaps there's a way in which I can have my sidebar view which needs to be in root, auctionpage and modal that has it's own path while not re-rendering my infinite scroll.

I got the router-view component in auctionpage as I'm suppose to.

Comment: `children` should be an array of objects

Comment: Oh lol, I suppose that answers that, sorry.